# Which event is called first? OnTick() or OnTimer()?

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

If I am processing OnTick events as well as OnTimer events, is there a preference in the queue?  When calculating time sensitive algorithms in seconds, I am wondering whether it is easier to write a whole EA inside OnTimer to avoid event handling issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnTimer` is the scheduled call. If your current `OnTimer` call takes long to process, the succeeding `OnTimer` might be skipped. Same with `OnTick`. 
If suppose the EA starts at 00:00:00.021 with `EventSetTimer(1);`, then the EA will call it each second at 21-th millisecond( well, some people says that is not always true but it is acceptable in most cases). At the same time it is possible that you receive more ticks during a second, or no ticks at all. If some action is important, `OnTimer()` may help with that.
What is the criteria that you should use `OnTimer()`? In MT4 one of the examples is using renko charts(in real time, for tests the call is off in MT4). For both MT4&5 `OnTimer()` is fine if you work with multicurrency expert. You may control `OnTick` of one symbol but not for both/all, `OnTimer` is called even if new tick did not arrive.